# Count Series of Values in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the total occurrence of  values in a list. See the raw Data:
[image]

In Laravel, see the code i have written but it is not correct, so i need assistance:

```
public static function ServiceNo($service,$fltno,$type)
{
       $res =  DB::table('tbname')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(distinct(nextSvr)) as svr'))
        ->where(['fltno'=>$fltno,'mtype'=>$type,'serviceType'=>$service])
        ->get(); 
        foreach($res as $r){
          $cnn =  $r->svr;
        }

    return $cnn;

}
```

The above code, will only count the distinct nextsvr, however,what i want is better explained like this: from the above, the first three 7's are counted as 1, the next three series is 1, etc, at the end total count for service type A will be 9 services. Please, i need help in this regard.

Comment: I understand what you mean but how is the databasing language supposed to distinguish between 1 and 1? Do you not have any other fields in your table that could help?

Comment: @MattJameson: Thanks take a look at the report from the DB, all i wanted is: if i count it manually like this, the first series i saw is 7 that is counted as 1, the next series is 9, that is 1, then next is 1 that is counted as 1 etc. At the end everything will be sum up as 9. If this is manual, then code can be written to solve this.What am i doing wrong with the code i have now.

Comment: do the sequences always come in 3?

Comment: No, it might be 4,even 10 at times

Comment: What happens if I sort the data, or insert it in a different order.  You cant rely on the insert order.  If you are creating them in batches, add a batch ID that you increment on each new batch.  There there is no issue, because you can count with group by batch ID.  The only way to count this is to pull every record from the table and manually count them with a switch when the data changes from 7 to something else, which just performance wise it bad, not counting all that can go wrong.  If they are by day add a date field and group on that.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: What you see is a list of materials for a particular service. So the service sequence is type A is 7,9,1,2. so i want to count total service for A from that data above.

Comment: @Dave so you need to count how many types of ServiceType A you have in your table? meaning for `Service Type A`, count distinct `Service Sequence` ?

Comment: @Dragos: yes  but more than that, it should count the sequence, ie distinct will return 6  as 7, 9 and 1 series occurred again. So it must be 9

Answer (score 0):

You should try below example

```
$count = DB::table('tablename')->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT name'));
```

**OR**

```
DB::table('tablename')->distinct('name')->count('name');
```

Comment: .What i want to count is distinct but not completely distinct, because, that will return 6 instead of 9. This means that  line 1-3  = 1, line 4-6= 1, line 7-9= 1 etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In MySQL it would be:

```
SET @prev := 0; 
SELECT sum(col) as distinct_count
FROM (
    SELECT *, if(@prev = nextSvr,  0,  1) as col,
    @prev := nextSvr
    FROM tbname
) x
```

By using a variable I think you can look out for changes between rows and increment a counter accordingly. So if the row changes add 1.

You could translate this into eloquent and use it:

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('SET @prev := 0'));

$count = DB::select(DB::raw("
    SELECT sum(col) as distinct_count
    FROM (
        SELECT *, if(@prev = nextSvr,  0,  1) as col,
        @prev := nextSvr
        FROM tbname
    ) x
"))
```

Comment: I don't understand your code please. Can you please translate it to eloquent

Comment: Unknown Column.

Comment: Call to a member function get() on array

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this, perhaps?

```
public function countServices(Request $request)
{
   $counter = 0;
   $fltno = '';

   $foo = DB::table('bar')
    ->where([
        ['fltno', '=', $request->fltno],
        ['mType', '=', $request->type],
        ['serviceType', '=', $request->service]
    ])
    ->get();

    foreach( $foo as $bar )
    {
        if( $fltno != $bar->fltno )
        {
            $fltno = $request->fltno;
            $counter++;
        }
    }

    return $counter;
}
```